# ArcGIS Pro field calculator based on values code

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser, syntaxerror

I'm trying to calculate a field to produce symbol codes for GPS units based on a field "Grade". I've tried cobbling together the code based on samples I found; but got syntax error.

The Code:

```
   if (Grade = A):
       return Block, Green
   elif (Grade = B):
       return Navaid, Green
   elif (Grade = C):
       return Navaid, Amber
   elif (Grade = D):
       return Navaid, Blue
   elif (Grade = F):
       return Navaid, Black
   elif (Grade = G):
       return Navaid, White
   elif (Grade = <Null>):
       return Navaid, Violet
   elif (Grade = UTL):
       return Navaid, Red
```

The Error:

```
File "<string>", line 2
 if (Grade = A):
       ^
SyntaxError:invalid syntax
```

Comment: This is a pure Python issue -- '`=`' is assignment, and '`==`' is equivalence. Your next issue will be lack of quotes on literals (e.g., '`'A'`')

Comment: Oh, and "Null" in Python is `None`.

Comment: Lastly, best practice on case in identifier names is to use `lowercase` for variables, `MixedCase` for classes, and `ALL_CAPS` for constants. Your "grade" variable should be `grade`.